# Essentials C# framework 3.5 book errors in example code

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading the book *Essentials C# 3.0 for .NET framework 3.5* from Mark Michaelis.  Since there are more classes involved I was hoping somebody had worked through the book and maybe had the same problem.

The code in chapter 7 fails(page 300). Listing 7.2 shows how to integrate an interface, I've written all of the code like it says in the book.
I'm getting the error:

> 'xxxx.ConsoleListControl.DisplayHeader(string[])': not all code path returns a value.

The code in question is:

```
    public static void List(string[] headers, Ilistable[] items)
    {
        int[] columnWidths = DisplayHeaders(headers);

        for (int count = 0; count < items.Length; count++)
        {
            string[] values = items[count].ColumnValues;
            DisplayItemsRow(columnWidths, values);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the column headers
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>returns an array of column widths</returns>
    private static int[] DisplayHeaders(string[] headers)
    {

    }

    private static void DisplayItemsRow(int[] columnWidths,string[] values)
    {

    }
}
```

The `string[]` headers arefilled with 4 items (FirstName, LastName, Address, Phone).
 I don't know what is causing this problem, or how to fix it.  I see `DisplayHeaders` has no value, and `columnwidths` also has no value.

I haven't put all of the code here; there are 5 classes and 1 interface.  I thought maybe that would be to much and not be needed.  If somebody wants all the code I will be happy to put it here.

Comment: Any method that has a type other than void must return an object of that type. So DisplayHeaders must return an integer array.

Comment: @Michael Or it could return `null`.  Or throw a `NotImplementedException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any method that has a type other than void must return an object of that type. So DisplayHeaders must return an integer array.

```
private static int[] DisplayHeaders(string[] headers)
```

`private` - access modifier; indicates this method can only be called from within the class

`static` - static modifier; this method does not need an instance to be called

`int[]` - return type; this is the type of the object that this method will return

`DisplayHeaders` - method name; this is how you refer to this method

`(string[] headers)` - parameters; this indicates which arguments you need to pass to the method

We can infer from the method summary that its implementation may look something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the column headers
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>returns an array of column widths</returns>
    private static int[] DisplayHeaders(string[] headers)
    {
        // builds a new int array with the same 
        // number of elements as the string array parameter
        int[] widths = new int[headers.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(headers[i]); // displays each header in the Console
            widths[i] = headers[i].Length; // populates the array with the string sizes
        }

        // the return keyword instructs the program to send the variable 
        // that follows back to the code that called this method
        return widths; 
    }
```

I would continue reading the chapter. More than likely the author fills in the implementation details of that method later on.

Answer (score 4):

Turn the page, or read again. I guess you're supposed to write code in the method, as it has a return type but no return statement.

Edit: alright, downloaded the PDF, the book explicitly says above this code listing:

> Consider another **example**

And in the code it says:

```
private static int[] DisplayHeaders(string[] headers)
{
    // ...
}
```

The `// ...` part indicates something not interesting to the concept being explained is left out for brevity.

The code is shown to explain what an interface can do (in this case printing a list of any kind of object that implements `Ilistable`), the static helper methods are irrelevant to this. The code is not meant to be run.

Comment: it should be put as comment not as answer!!

Comment: If OP posted the code exactly as in the book, this is the answer. I'm not going to guess what is supposed to be in that method.

Answer (score 0):

The method DisplayHeaders says it returns an array of integers (`int[]`) but it is not in fact returning anything. There is quite likely code a little bit later on that fills in the method to do something useful, but in order to make the code compile, it needs to return an array. A simple way to do that would be to change it to

```
private static int[] DisplayHeaders(string[] headers)
{
    return new int[0];
}
```

This causes it to return an empty array of integers.